# How to select duplicate rows in SQL 2021

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This query will give us John, Sam, Tom, Tom because they all have the same email.

However, what I want is to get duplicates with the same email and name.

That is, I want to get "Tom", "Tom".

The reason I need this: I made a mistake, and allowed inserting duplicate name and email values. Now I need to remove/change the duplicates, so I need to find them first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query with the 'number', that gives you how many duplicates and query only illustrates the duplicates. Hope you understand.

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*) AS number
FROM table
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING number > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       name, email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
               name, email
            ORDER BY 
               name, email
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        yourTableName
)
---To Delete Duplicate Records ---
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```